# OpenAM - Get user realm using OpenAM's rest API

Tags: openam

Using OpenAM's REST API, i'm trying to get a realm on which a user is created. User attributes that are retrieved using /identity/attributes service don't retrive the user realm.

Is there a way to get a realm on which a user is created using OpenAM rest API?

I'm using OpenAM v13.

Answer (score 0):

Users are not really "created" in a specific realm as OpenAM is not the owner of identity information but consumes identity information from configured user data stores.

So an OpenAM user identity object actually "belongs" to a realm.

The '/identity/' REST endpoints are deprecated and you should use the new REST services https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/dev-guide/chap-client-dev#rest-api-crud-identity

If you use https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/dev-guide/chap-client-dev#rest-api-read-identity and you get a successful response you can be sure the user identity belongs to the given realm.